# Optimistic block execution and reverting state

Tags: frame

I've been playing around with substrate a lot lately and I was wondering how one would go with implementing optimistic block execution.

What I mean by this is that transactions are executed *as if* they are valid, but their validity depends on some criteria that is only available to know *after* block propagation. Therefore, if an invalid trasaction is found, nodes would have to revert the world state to the state resulting from the last valid transaction.

More specifically, I was wondering whether or not this is doable within FRAME.

Answer (score 1):

You could look at the [`ValidateUnsigned`](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/frame_support/pallet_prelude/trait.ValidateUnsigned.html).

This check is at the transaction pool level. Once the verification fails, the transaction will be dropped and won't be broadcast.

There are a lot of examples in the substrate/frontier repository.

Here is [one](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/im-online/src/lib.rs#L551).

Comment: Thanks for you answer, however I believe what you propose assumes you can detect if a transaction is valid at the transaction pool level. As I explained, in my case it is only possible to know if a transaction is valid *after* the block has been built and propagated.

Comment: could you give an example? what transaction will be invaild after the propagated?

Comment: With in mind optimistic execution, one could think of the example where transactions in the block are executed *as if* they are valid, and once the block has been propagated, a validator can flag a fraudulent transaction that was included in the block. In this case, nodes have to revert to the state given by the execution of the last valid transaction in the block.